# Querie mongodb com regex

Tags: regex, mongodb

Estou tentando encontrar a melhor forma de fazer essa querie no mongodb.
Eu tenho esse numero 42999234180 e tenho uma tabela de prefixos que variam de 3 a 7 caracteres, gostaria que ao buscar por 4299234180 ele retornasse o valor que fosse mais semelhante ao numero inteiro, por exemplo no banco eu tenho salvo

```
429
4299
42999 <--- nesse caso ele retornaria esse resultado.
429998
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que você está procurando por algo como procura de string por resultado aproximado (tenta procurar por "aproximate string matching"). Pensando por um momento, se você procura pelo número inteiro não existe a possibilidade de achar resultados "menores", a não ser que esteja usando algum resultado aproximado.

Existem algumas técnicas para isso, usei [esse](http://www.catalysoft.com/articles/StrikeAMatch.html) algoritmo em um projeto. Ele compara pares de letras dentro da sua String. Dá uma olhada.

Answer (score 0):

O que você deseja não tem a ver com REGEX, pois é necessário realizar operações aritméticas.

#### Resolução

```
CREATE TABLE prefixos(
  prefixo INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO prefixos (prefixo) VALUES
('429'),
('4299'),
('42999'),
('429998');

SELECT
    P.prefixo,
    min(P.prefixo - Q.pos)
FROM    
    prefixos P
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT  prefixo,
            substring('4299234180' from 0 for char_length(prefixo::varchar)+1)::integer as pos
        FROM    prefixos
    ) as Q ON Q.prefixo = P.prefixo
WHERE
    (P.prefixo - Q.pos) > 0
GROUP BY
    P.prefixo
ORDER BY
    2
LIMIT   1
```

#### Explicação

Para resolver seu problema usei a seguinte logica :

- Capturar a parte do numero correspondente ao tamanho do prefixo. Prefixo `429` tem len = 3, então vou capturar os 3 primeiros caracteres do seu numero.

A parte de faz isso é :

```
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT  prefixo,
        substring('4299234180' from 0 for char_length(prefixo::varchar)+1)::integer as pos
    FROM    prefixos
) as Q ON Q.prefixo = P.prefixo
```

- Apos ter a correspondente do numero ao prefixo realizo uma operação aritmética para remover os igual a zero pois quer disser que a um prefixo superior que deve se adequar.
  `(P.prefixo - Q.pos) > 0`
- Por fim , verifico a menos variação possível assim tendo o prefixo que melhor se adapta. `min(P.prefixo - Q.pos)`

#### Nota

- A base que usei foi PostgreSQL, talvez seja necessário adaptar alguma coisa, pois nem todos SGBD tem as mesmas funções.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda mas eu so uso mongodb como banco de dados, nao tenho experiencia com SQL somente com NOSQL, e Regex é algo nativo dentro do mongodb.